# In Server 2022 Hyper-V, how to fix partition alignment inside VM after Veeam restore?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2022

Recently I converted a bare-metal Server 2022 machine to a Hyper-V guest VM. I used Veeam Windows Agent 6.0 (Free) to back up the bare metal machine and restore it as a virtual machine. I created two dynamically-expanding VHDX disks for the restore of the system drive and data drive. The system seems to be working fine, but I am now getting these warnings from the virtual machine:

"Application Event Log, ID=264, Source=Microsoft-Windows-Defrag, Message: The storage optimizer couldn't complete slab consolidation on (C:) because: The slab consolidation / trim operation cannot be performed because the volume alignment is invalid. (0x89000029)"

I believe this fsutil command points to the problem:

```
>fsutil fsinfo sectorinfo c:
LogicalBytesPerSector : 512
PhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity : 4096
PhysicalBytesPerSectorForPerformance : 4096
FileSystemEffectivePhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity : 4096
Device Alignment : Aligned (0x000)
Partition alignment on device : **Not Aligned (0xc00)** <----
Performs Normal Seeks
Trim Supported
Not DAX capable
Is Thinly-Provisioned, SlabSize : 33,554,432 bytes (32.0 MB)
```

Apparently Veeam did not align the C: partition on restore. How can I fix that now, or do I need to?